Is the matrix totally unimodular
If $A_1$ and $A_2$ is totally unimodular (TU), and $I$ is a identity matrix. I am wondering if the matrix $A$ is TU:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 & I \\
  0 & A_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thanks for your help!

I try to proof it like this:
For each matrix like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  A & I \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  A \\
  I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
det of them is $\pm1$ or $0$.
For each submatrix of $A$ or $I$, det is $\pm1$ or $0$.
But i dont know the det of this way:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 & I \\
  0 & A_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What have you tried?

Notational clarification. Let $I_{(n_1,n_2)}$ denote a matrix of the form $[I_{n_1} \ \ \ 0]$, $\left[\matrix{I_{n_1}\\0}\right]$, or $I_{n_1}$ when (resp.) $n_1<n_2$, $n_1> n_2$, or $n_1=n_2$.

Answer. Given two totally unimodal matrices $A_1\in\text{M}_{n_1}(\mathbb{Z}), A_2\in\text{M}_{n_1}(\mathbb{Z})$, then the matrix you have constructed $A=\left[\matrix{A_1&&I_{(n_1,n_2)}\\0&&A_2}\right]$ will be totally unimodal as well.
But why is this? To understand why this is, let us start by observing that all submatrices in  $[A_1]$, $[A_2]$ $[I_{(n_1,n_2)}]$, $[0]$, $\left[\matrix{A_1\\0}\right],$ and $[0\ \ \ A_2]$ will have determinant $0,\pm1$. (For the first two, this is a consequence of the definition of TU. For the latter four, it's an easy result to check.) So all that remains to check is whether submatrices in $[A_1\ \ \ I_{(n_1,n_2)}],$ $\left[\matrix{I_{(n_1,n_2)}\\A_2}\right]$, and $\left[\matrix{A_1&&I_{(n_1,n_2)}\\0&&A_2}\right]$ (i.e. submatrices which aren't confined to any single nor two of the matrix squares) will all have determinant $0,\pm1$.

For any submatrix contained in $[A_1\ \ \ I]$ (and not entirely in $[A_1]$ nor $[I]$), then either: (Case 1) You will have a submatrix with a column of zeros, or (Case 2) you will have a submatrix of the form $\left[A_1^\text{sub}\ \ \ I_0\right]$ where $A_1^\text{sub}$ denotes a sub matrix in $A_1$, $I_0$ denotes a matrix of the form $\left[\matrix{I_{(k,n_2)}\\0}\right]$ for some $k<n_1$. In case (i), it is immediately clear that all submatrices will have determinant $0$. In case (ii), cofactor expansion reveals that the determinant of this matrix will in fact be equal to that of a submatrix in $A_1^\text{sub}$, hence will have determinant $0,\pm1$. Since all submatrices in $[A_1\ \ \ I]$ have determinant $0,\pm1$ implies the same result for $\left[\matrix{I\\A_2}\right]$, we're done with the first two troublesome situations.

Given any submatrix contained in all four matrix squares, then we have a matrix of the form $\left[\matrix{A_1^{sub}&&I_0\\0&&A^{sub}_2}\right]$ where $I_0=\left[\matrix{0&&I_{n_x}\\0&&0}\right]$ for some $n_x<\text{min}(n_1,n_2)$. Cofactor expansion reveals that this question can be simplified down to $\left[\matrix{(A_1^{sub})^{sub}&&0\\0&& (A^{sub}_2)^{sub}}\right]$, which'll have determinant $0,\pm1$ (This is easy to check noting that $(A_1^{sub})^{sub}$ and $(A^{sub}_2)^{sub}$ will be TU).


And with that, we're done.

Original Answer. (Irrelevant.) The matrix you have constructed will be Unimodal. Why is this? Recall that any matrix $M\in\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ which is invertible will be a unimodal. Hence, if we were to denote two unimodal matrices $A_1,A_2$, then the matrix $A=\left[\matrix{A_1&&I\\0&&A_2}\right]$ will have inverse $A^{-1}=\left[\matrix{A_1^{-1}&&-A_1^{-1}A_2^{-1}\\0&&A_2^{-1}}\right]$.

TU is a matrix that is invertible, but is a invertible matrix is TU?

thank you very much

@HuangFrank Edited my original response: I got some concepts mixed up. This should be good, though it is a bit lengthy. Let me know if you have any further questions.

i am sorry but i do not know how to make $\left[\matrix{A_1^{sub}&&I_0\0&&A^{sub}_2}\right]$ down to $\left[\matrix{(A_1^{sub})^{sub}&&0\0&& (A^{sub}_2)^{sub}}\right]$

@HuangFrank Admittedly, it is a lot to type out. So you do make a good remark in that it isn't the neatest thing to prove...my recommendation for the moment would be to consider several example matrices. The logic should "click" eventually. I can certainly elaborate tomorrow morning (just remind me via a comment here) if it still doesn't entirely make sense.

I found a way to proof it! And i found  \begin{bmatrix}A & B\0 & D\end{bmatrix} is TU if and only if \begin{bmatrix}A & B\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}B\D\end{bmatrix} are TU, is it right?

Prove $\begin{bmatrix}A_1 & A_2 \ 0 & A_3 \ \end{bmatrix}$ is TU: I use matrix operations to make the first row into $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}$. It is easy to prove that the new matrix still consists of $\pm1, 0$. The new matrix still like $\begin{bmatrix}A_1^{sub} & A_2^{sub} \ 0 & A_3^{sub} \ \end{bmatrix}$, and we can repeat that until we reach the case of a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Answer my problem: Actually, we can prove another inference: Prove that if $\begin{bmatrix}A_1 & A_2\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} A_2 \\ A_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is TU, $\begin{bmatrix}A_1 & A_2 \\ 0 & A_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is TU: I use matrix operations to make the first row into $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}$. It is easy to prove that the new matrix still consists of $\pm1, 0$. The new matrix still like $\begin{bmatrix}A_1^{sub} & A_2^{sub} \\ 0 & A_3^{sub} \\ \end{bmatrix}$, and we can repeat that until we reach the case of a $1\times 1$ matrix.
In this problem,  $\begin{bmatrix}A & I\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}I \\ A\end{bmatrix}$ is TU, so $A=\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 & I \\
  0 & A_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is TU.
